# Generating Service Proxy for Team Foundation Service from Visual Studio

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to do some custom integration with [Visual Studio Team Foundation Service](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/). Please note, this is NOT the on-premises version. I've figured out how to query the service via OData. I also found [this sample](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36230). For the life of me though, I can't figure out how they created the service proxy to TFS. This proxy contains the helper classes which makes development easier.

How do I add a service proxy to Visual Studio Team Foundation Service? Typically, I would just use a URL. However, I can't seem to figure out which URL to use.  Thank you

Comment: Why not use the TFS SDK?  What is it that you're trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out the tfs odata api documentation.
Also, here is a link to sample code that creates a web proxy for a TFS work item browser.

Hope this helps.

[A Windows Store (WinRT) TFS Work Item Browser](http://ajryan.github.com/blog/2013/02/04/a-windows-store-winrt-tfs-work-item-browser/)

[Team Foundation Server OData API](https://tfsodata.visualstudio.com/)